# Problema ao carregar campos somente necessários usando ResultSetTransformer no Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

Estou tentando desenvolver um método para através de um `SQL` puro, buscar somente os campos necessários a minha `query` e por fim, já trazer o objeto já mapeado.

No caso o objeto seria `PropostaCartao` e dentro dele teria um outro chamado `Filial`. Gostaria de saber como fazer o `SQL` para trazer o `id` da `PropostaCartao` e o `id` da `Filial` e indicar que ambos são do tipo `Long` usando o recurso `Scalar` pois o campo é do tipo Long.

Então, gostaria de saber como fazer a `query` e o método para popular o `id` da `PropostaCartao` e o `id` da `Filial`.

Obrigado

Comment: Como você está fazendo? Inclua o código que seja possível reproduzir o seu problema.

Comment: Cara acabou que eu implementei uma `interface` `ResultTransformer` e assim repassei os campos para o objeto.

Comment: @Macario1983, coloque uma resposta mais completa, mesma que seja a sua própria pergunta, para a pessoa que passar pela mesma dúvida ter mais detalhes de como você solucionou :)

Comment: @Dherik desculpa, é a falta de tempo. Mas vou postar

Comment: @Dherik, demorou mas cumpri! Vlw

Answer (score 0):

O meu objetivo é o seguinte, fazer uma `query` e popular o objeto com esse retorno.

Meu desafio se deu porque eu não sei retornar o objeto igual se faz uma consulta via `objeto` no `Hibernate`, pois tem vários objetos associados ao `objeto` principal.

Então eu fiz que poderia eu implementar uma `Interface` `ResultTransformer` que tem dois métodos.

O método `transformTuple(Object[] tupla, String[] alias)` é onde se faz a associação do `objeto` ao resultado da `query`.

O método `transformList(List lista)` retorna a `lista`.

O que precisam entender é o seguinte, no primeiro método informado acima ocorre o seguinte processo:

Você vai instanciar um `objeto` novo, e popular cada atributo dele, assim:

```
PropostaCartao propostaCartao = new PropostaCartao();
propostaCartao.setId(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(tupla[0])));
```

Informo que a ordem do objeto tupla segue a ordem dos campos na query, ou seja, se vc fizer assim:

```
SELECT campo_1, campo_2 FROM tabela;
```

Na hora de transformar vc vai fazer o seguinte:

```
Objeto objeto = new Objeto();
objeto.setcampo1(tupla[0]);
objeto.setcampo2(tupla[1]);
```

E na hora de executar a query chamar a classe criada desta forma:

```
String sql = this.filtrarDados(filter);
Query query = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession()
              .createSQLQuery(sql)
              .setResultTransformer(new RelatorioExtratoLojistaAnaliticaResultTransformer());
```

No método `setResultTransformer`, vc coloca sua classe recém criada.